# WordPress Theme: Standalone theme need index.php file ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I suddenly got got an error when coding - wordpress -> theme:
[image]

I don't understand why this is the case as I have an index.php page. Also the css stylesheet is there as well. style.css also has the following commented

style.css

```
Theme Name: samirTheme
Author: samir
Author URI: www.wordpress.com
Version: 1.0
Description: This is a cool theme
Template: Test1
```

Here is the folder structure

[image]

New to wordpress. So confused as to why the theme is broken and not showing up in wordpress. Any ideas?

Comment: you are missing a template.php and style.css

Comment: But I have style.css in the css folder. I didn't have template.php this whole time and the theme was working i.e. not broken and active. Why now would it break

Comment: Is it because I created a new page in wordpress admin?

Comment: you must have style.css in theme folder or link it from functions.php otherwise it won't work, try it

Comment: I have the enqueue function is functions.php i.e. wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css');

Comment: check here how to load style https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/     https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: Its weird because the css was working fine and everything was good. I created a page in admin and then broken theme

Comment: @Shaz could you pls help how can i solve my issue, my code: https://justpaste.it/6f3tq

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
The solution way actually very simple. I found that it was really hard to find a good resource for the answer so I am answering here.

The style.css was missing: template: theme in the commented header i.e.

```
/*
 Theme Name:   samirTheme
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfifteen <--------------------------------------------
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

Comment: @Rathinam sorry for late reponse. copy and paste this code into your css file

Comment: This is applicable only if your intention is to make a child theme of twentyfifteen. If your theme is standalone, Spencer has the answer.

Comment: Solved my issue.

Answer (score 10):

In order for WordPress to recognize the set of theme template files as a valid theme, the style.css file needs to be located in the root directory of your theme, not a subdirectory.

So main theme css file in root -> then enqueue a 2nd style sheet that has all the styles in it - if you want it to be in /css/

Example header of css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Seventeen
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
Description: Twenty Seventeen brings your site to life with immersive featured images and subtle animations. With a focus on business sites, it features multiple sections on the front page as well as widgets, navigation and social menus, a logo, and more. Personalize its asymmetrical grid with a custom color scheme and showcase your multimedia content with post formats. Our default theme for 2017 works great in many languages, for any abilities, and on any device.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: twentyseventeen
Tags: one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-header, accessibility-ready, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, custom-logo, editor-style, featured-images, footer-widgets, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

For more info read this:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/

Comment: @Rathinam - go to the link I posted above in my answer and compare it agains what you have written. Or just copy/paste directly from wordpress and then edit the content.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me. I have all the necessary files (as two files only required index and style) one thing I have noticed if you have a folder for your style.css file you will get the error message as above.

So I cross-checked and even moved the and deleted the index file from the main folder.

If I delete index.php file from main folder, and place it inside the css folder it works.

I do not know why it happened. But it seems me it need an index file inside the style folder or style.css files to be placed in the main folder.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by character encoding. For example:

```
$ file -I style.css
style.css: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
$ file -I style-error.css
style-error.css: text/plain; charset=utf-16le
```

Copying and pasting CSS code from web pages (*e.g.*, tutorial articles) into the CSS file itself is a common cause for getting tripped up with this. If the CSS code contains special characters, sometimes the file editor will try to change the character encoding of the CSS file to accommodate for all of the characters being added.

Long after the fact when this question was asked, but hope that helps anyone else looking for an answer.